# btrfs formatted partion not mounting from fstab

Tags: btrfs

I have this new mageia 4 setup with some btrfs partitions.

My root "/" is on btrfs, working fine.
from fstab:

```
UUID=b2b0263e-a04a-4bd7-86d7-d2ec19a90b84 / btrfs relatime 0 0
```

then I have a different btrfs formatted partition for steam data on /dev/sdc3

I can mount /dev/sdc3 on /steam manually as root, no problem.

```
mount /dev/sdc3 /steam -o relatime
```

However, I cannot mount this filesystem from fstab:

```
/dev/sdc3 /steam btrfs relatime 0 0
```

I also tried:

```
UUID=487e4905-724d-40dd-a83b-d3b576b61d59 /steam btrfs relatime 0 0
```

(found the UUID using blkid)

When I try to mount this from fstab, I get an error:

```
[root@novazembla ~]# mount /steam
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc3,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

Of course, I checked as suggested using:

```
journalctl -n
dmesg | less
```

but there are no indications of what's going on.

then I tried:

btrfs device scan

and tried to mount from fstab again to no avail (same error and no logging info)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Am really sorry, the hour must have gotten to me because while I was actually sure I made a btrfs partition, I actually made an ext3 partition...

```
/dev/sdc3 on /steam type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered)
```

## feeling stupid

Only after fu####ng myself up and posting here did the light finally shine through.